# Why is there "undefined" text in the beginning of my string?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that concatenates together the results from an AJAX request.

For some reason, my final string starts with "undefined".

Here is a simplified example that reproduces the problem:

```js
    // In practice, fetched via AJAX from a server
    var vendors = [{ id_vendor: 'V0001' }, { id_vendor: 'V0002' }];

    var row_vendor;

    vendors.forEach(function (value) {
      row_vendor += value.id_vendor;
    });
 
    alert(row_vendor); // undefinedV0001V0002
```

Why does the value alerted display a leading "undefined"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not initializing your variable, so its value is `undefined`. Concatenating a string coerces it to the string `"undefined"` before the concatenation.

Consider:

```
var x
alert(x + "test") // undefinedtest
```

Instead, initialize your variable to an empty string before performing concatenation:

```
var x = ""
alert(x + "test") // test
```

Note that functionally it is much cleaner to first extract the property you're interested in and then simply `join` them together:

```
$.map(vendor, function (v) { return v.vendor_id }).join('')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `row_vendor` variable is not assigned an initial value, so it starts out `undefined` and then using the `+=` operator on it to concatenate a string results in `undefined` becoming the string `"undefined"` (plus the `"v0001"`). Simply set it to an empty string when you declare it:

```
var row_vendor = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on this line

```
$.each(vendor, function(i, value) {
  row_vendor += value.id_vendor;
});
```

In order to use `row_vendor` for concatenation purpose, you first have to have a default value assigned to it. So what you would need to do is:

```
var row_vendor = ""; // set it to empty string by default
$.each(vendor, function(i, value) {
   row_vendor += value.id_vendor;
});
```

On a sidenote, you can also concatenate a string using an array. I prefer it this way since it's more pretty and readable.

```
var row_vendor = []; // empty array
$.each(vendor, function(i, value) {
   row_vendor.push(value.id_vendor);
});
console.log(row_vendor.join(",")); // this will separate each value with a comma
```